# why kubernetes api versions are like domain names

Tags: kubernetes

Why Kubernetes API versions are like domain names, e.g. as below? What signifies networking, k8s, and io separated by dots?

```
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
networking.k8s.io/v1
networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to programming.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes objects are organized into API groups. `rbac.authorization.k8s.io` is one of them, holding objects such as Roles, RoleBindings, ClusterRoles and ClusterRoleBindings. `networking.k8s.io` is another where we would find Ingresses, IngressClasses and NetworkPolicies.

Kubernetes objects are versioned, facilitating transitions in their schema. When an object's APIversion is set to `rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1`, its description should match the v1 schema - relative to object kind (role, clusterrole, ...), in that API group.

You could find more about those schemas, using `kubectl explain <object-name>`.

You can list known object names and their api group, with `kubectl api-resources`